# How to move laravel projevt from Wamp to lamp centoS 7

Tags: php, linux, laravel, laravel-5, centos7

I need to move existing laravel 5 project to linux centos 7. I'm going to install lamp, copy source files and database backup and move them to new centos 7 server. Is there anything I should take into account? I moved a lot of pure PHP webpages but never laravel projects. Help appreciated :)

Comment: laravel 5 is too old and deprecated consider upgrading.

Comment: Consider reviewing the laravel documentation for deployments. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/deployment

Answer (score 0):

You should pay attention to the following:

- PHP and mysql version. Laravel 5 tends to break with certain PHP versions
- Having document root as /public folder
- Make sure to have the bootstrap and the storage folders writable
- Make sure to clean the cache upon migration

Comment: What I meant is: does it need anything more like composer or something to be installed on server? or should I just move source and db and everything will be fine?

Comment: Laraver does not need much in this regard. Correct versions of PHP and MySQL, Composer and it will take care of other dependecies.